# Pycord - Edit bot messages using Slash Commands

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

I am trying to make a command to edit a bot message using the message ID, i made a prefix one and it worked well, but im not sure how to make a slash command one to make things easier, here is what i tried:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="edit", description="Edits the bot messages", guild=discord.Object(id=824342611774144543))
async def edit(self, id: Option(int, description="Message ID", required=True), message: Option(str, description="New Input Message", required=True)):
    msg = self.bot.get_message(id)
    await msg.edit(message)
```

The slash command shows no options when i try to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands require a `ctx` parameter for the context of the command.

Pycord uses the actual guild ids in the **`guild_ids`** parameter instead of `discord.Object`s for `guild` in discord.py.

Since you have the `self` parameter, I'm assuming you're in a cog. You'll need to use the `@discord.slash_command` decorator instead.

Also, `bot.get_message` checks the cache, which means it won't find the message all the time. You should instead use `await ctx.channel.fetch_message(id)` which makes an API call and will find the message if it exists in the current channel.

```py
@discord.slash_command(name="edit", description="Edits the bot messages", guild_ids=[824342611774144543])  # use guild_ids instead
async def edit(
    self,
    ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,  # missing ctx parameter
    id: Option(int, description="Message ID", required=True),
    message: Option(str, description="New Input Message", required=True)
):
    msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(id)  # fetch instead
    await msg.edit(message)
```

If you have other questions about pycord, it's better to ask in the [support server](https://discord.gg/pycord).